# matplotlib - subplots with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with plotting multiple subplots. I would like to set the PHYSICAL aspect ratio of the subplots to a fixed value. 
In my example I have 12 subplots (4 rows and 3 columns) on a landscape A4 figure. There all subplots are nicely placed on the whole figure, and for all subplots the height is nearly equal to the width.

But if I change the layout of my figure to portrait, the subplots are stretched vertically.
And this is exactly what should not happen. I would like to have the same height and width of the subplots as on the landscape figure. Is there a possibility that the aspect ratio of the subplots stay the same?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

EDIT:
I have found a workaround. But this just works for non-logarithmic axes...

```
aspectratio=1.0
ratio_default=(ax.get_xlim()[1]-ax.get_xlim()[0])/(ax.get_ylim()[1]-ax.get_ylim()[0])
ax.set_aspect(ratio_default*aspectratio)
```

Comment: As of matplotlib version 3.8, the [`set_box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-box-aspect) method with `aspect = 1` achieves what you want for both linear and log scales. Note that this method is **different** from the `set_aspect` method. For more details, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78027756/13809128) below.

Answer (score 22):

Actually, what you're wanting is quite simple...  You just need to make sure that `adjustable` is set to `'box'` on your axes, and you have a set aspect ratio for the axes (anything other than `'auto'`).

You can either do this with the `adjustable` kwarg when you create the subplots. Alternatively, you can do this after their creation by calling `ax.set_adjustable('box')`, or by calling `ax.set_aspect(aspect, adjustable='box')` (where aspect is either `'equal'` or a number).

Now, regardless of how the figure is resized, the subplots will maintain the same aspect ratio.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, adjustable='box', aspect=0.3)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

ax1.plot(range(10))
ax2.plot(range(10))

plt.show()
```

---

Now, compare how the top subplot responds to resizing, vs. how the bottom subplot responds:

---

The initial plot
[image]

Resized to a vertical layout:
[image]

Resized to a horizontal layout:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this sets only the aspect ratio of the axes of the subplots. Since I have many different ranges of my axes I would have to set this aspect ratio for every subplot individually. So what I wanted to do is to set the hight and width of my subplots (and not just the axes) to a specific aspect ratio.

Answer (score 7):

Your workaround works for me. After plotting the data, I call the following function:

```
def fixed_aspect_ratio(ratio):
    '''
    Set a fixed aspect ratio on matplotlib plots 
    regardless of axis units
    '''
    xvals,yvals = gca().axes.get_xlim(),gca().axes.get_ylim()

    xrange = xvals[1]-xvals[0]
    yrange = yvals[1]-yvals[0]
    gca().set_aspect(ratio*(xrange/yrange), adjustable='box')
```

Comment: This worked well for me. I modified the function to accept an `ax` argument so that I could apply it to subplots. I also replaced the `gca().axes` with `ax` and `gca()` with `ax`.

Answer (score 4):

In reply to the remark about the solution not working for logarithmic plots in the edit to the original question - you need to adapt as follows:

```
def fixed_aspect_ratio_loglog(ratio):
    '''
    Set a fixed aspect ratio on matplotlib loglog plots 
    regardless of axis units
    '''
    xvals,yvals = gca().axes.get_xlim(),gca().axes.get_ylim()

    xrange = log(xvals[1])-log(xvals[0])
    yrange = log(yvals[1])-log(yvals[0])
    gca().set_aspect(ratio*(xrange/yrange), adjustable='box')
```

(Adaptation for semilog plots should now be obvious)

Comment: Who is `gca()`?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout [get current axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html).

Answer (score 0):

As of matplotlib version 3.8, the [`set_box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-box-aspect) method with `aspect = 1` achieves what the other answers describe, for both linear and log scales. Note that this method is **different** from the [`set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-aspect) method. Here is an example that uses `set_box_aspect` with linearly-scaled axes:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.random.rand(10) * 5 + 10 # example data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=1)
ax.grid(visible=True, which="both")
```

[image]

The same example with log-scaled axes:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.random.rand(10) * 5 + 10 # example data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=1)
ax.grid(visible=True, which="both")
```

[image]

More examples that use `set_box_aspect` can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_box_aspect.html).